# Min value of $\cos(\sin x)+\sin(\cos x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The max value of $f(x) = \sin(\cos x) + \cos(\sin x)$ is equal to $1 + \sin 1$.  What is the minimum value of $f(x)$?

I found the max value using that range $\sin(\cos x)$ is $[- \sin 1, \sin 1]$ and range of $\cos(\sin x)$ is $[ \cos 1, 1]$ and the maximum of both occurs at $x=0$.  Although I can't find the min value using this approach. Please try to find this  without using graphing calculators.

Comment: ...max value of "$\sin (\cos x) + \cos( \sin x) = 1+ \sin (1)$" makes no sense.  It is like saying "find the max value of $f(x) = 2$."

Comment: f(x)=2 is a constant function . so it has no max or min . Maybe you took it in a wrong way I meant to say max value of sin(cosx) +cos(sinx) is 1 +sin1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this graph of your function to see the multiple minima, essential for understanding and solving your problem.

[image]

Comment: Yeah one can easily use the calculator and get the answer but i am asking is there any way we find min value of sin(cosx) +cos(sinx) without the help of calculators

Comment: You should add that in the question perhaps @Raghav

Comment: Added .Thankyou